# What does this sentence mean to you?

Tags: grammar

Example 1

> > Going through difficulties, **some aboriginal people** even started to create literature in their own languages.

Grammar books say the main clause and its subordinate clause have to have the same subject so that we can omit the subordinate clause's subject, like my Example 1. However, I think there are multiple interpretations for Example 1.

In my opinion, Example 1 means

> > "After **some aboriginal people** went through difficulties, **they** even started to create literature."

However, my guts feeling is telling me it means

> > "After **aboriginal people(all aboriginal people in general)** went through difficulties, **some of them** even started to create literature."

What do you guys think? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its the first one. Some aboriginal people were going through difficulties and some then started to create literature. It makes more sense to keep the subject as a common thread throughout the sentence, not changing from "some" to "all" midway through the sentence.